# How to make a new (object?) of a class with a name of a variable?

Tags: java, class

Let's say I have a class `myClass` and a `String myString`. How would I do this:

```
myClass [value of myString] = new myClass;
```

Comment: Using a string value as a variable? You can't. Is there a reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a dynamic variable in Java. Still, you can use a `Map<String, Object>` to have the `String myString` as the key and set the new value as new instance of your class:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(myString, new MyClass());
```

If you're sure your map will only contain `MyClass` instances, then you can use `Map<String, MyClass>`.

```
Map<String, MyClass> map = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the value of a string variable as a variable name.  Java doesn't allow that.

However, with a `Map`, you can associate a string (as a key) to a value:

```
Map<String, MyClass> map = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
map.put(myString, new MyClass());
```

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but in Java, that's as close as you're going to get.

Comment: looks like we have the same idea and took the same time to write our answers.

Comment: How is strong typing relevant? It's more about compile-time naming :)

Comment: @Armen, I don't think strong typing has anything to do with it.  The Java compiler expects variable identifier names to have a name directly in the source file at compile time, and the identifier is not reliant, and cannot be reliant, on any runtime value such as the value of `myString`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to store your `Object`s indexed by your `String`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String myString = "something";
    final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(myString, new Object());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using generics and creating a base class with type parameters

```
public MyGenClass<K,V>{
 private Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,v>();

 public Map<K,V> getMap(){
  return map;
 }

 public void setMap(Map<K,V> iMap){
   map=iMap;
 }

}
```

using this class, you can easily get different kind of maps while having similar methods.

enjoy :)